# Process y_pred and y_true chunk wise in custom loss function in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

In my Tensorflow model y_pred contains probabilities from 0 to 1 and y_true contains labels of 0 and 1.

In my custom loss function I'd like to use the information of 4 (or n) consecutive pairs of y_true and y_pred.

In numpy I could do something like this

```
y_true=np.array([1,1,1,1,0,0,0,])
y_pred=np.array([0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2])

def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    n=len(t)
    res= 0
    for i in range(0,n,4):
        res += np.sum(y_true[i:i+4])-np.sum(y_pred[i:i+4])
    return res
```

Is there a way to achieve this in Tensorflow with tensors?

I am using Tensorflow version 2.2.0 and python 3.8

Comment: is `len(y_true) % 4 == 0`? or are there sometimes fewer?

Comment: there's no reason you take them four by four though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking care of when the `len(y_true) % 4 != 0`:

```
@tf.function
def custom_loss_tf(y_true, y_pred):
  length = tf.shape(y_true)[0]
  end_i = length % 4
  start_y_true, end_y_true = y_true[:length-end_i], y_true[length-end_i:]
  start_y_pred, end_y_pred = y_pred[:length-end_i], y_pred[length-end_i:]
  sum_start_y_true = tf.reduce_sum(tf.reshape(start_y_true, (-1,4)), axis=0)
  sum_start_y_pred = tf.reduce_sum(tf.reshape(start_y_pred, (-1,4)), axis=0)
  res = tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(sum_start_y_true, tf.float32)) - tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(sum_start_y_pred, tf.float32))
  res_ending = tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(end_y_true, tf.float32) - tf.cast(end_y_pred, tf.float32))
  return res_ending + res
```

Your function doesn't make a lot of sense though, you are calculating sums of sums. Can't you just sum everything?

Comment: Yes the function does not make sense I just wanted to know hot to handle the arrays in chunks.